# incorrect determination of the number of channels when decoding the opus

Tags: audio, codec, opus

I am sending audio chunks to the opus decoding function in C++. I was sending chunks of 1024 bytes, but in this case the decoder incorrectly determined the number of channels and, it seems, worked out incorrectly. For some audio, you need to send ~6000 bytes a piece, for others ~2000 bytes. I went through and found these values. What could be the reason for this behavior?
I have read the opus documentation. The codec header can't be that big.

How I think it works. The decoder reads the header of the first chunk and returns the number of channels. But for different audio, it needs a lot more bytes of audio to determine the number of channels.

Comment: Ogg Opus files? Are you using `libopusfile` at a high level or using `libopus` to decode directly?

Comment: libsoxr. I didn't write the c++ decoder.

Answer (score 0):

The number of bytes needed to initially decode Ogg Opus files most likely depends on the size of the [Ogg pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg_page) (up to 64KB).  During past decoding tests, I noticed that Ogg files with lower bitrates and frame sizes generated smaller pages, and thus decoded sooner with fewer bytes.  It's worth inspecting your Ogg Opus files with `opusinfo` (see [opus-tools](https://opus-codec.org/downloads/)) to find the correlation.